# The computer keeps running both %pass3% AND %pass4% when I only want it to run one

Tags: batch-file

I don't really know how to explain this so please just run this in a batch file because my knowledge of MS-DOS is minimal. I hope you'll be able to see what I mean in the title. When it asks "Activate Order 66?" answer no. The computer then shows both %pass3% and %pass4%. Both raw inputs pop up and when you type no it doesn't come out how it's supposed to. And, in case you were wondering, this is a prank for my friend.
Code here:

```
@echo off
color 0a
@echo Are you sure you want to bypass the nuclear firewall?
pause
@echo Enter the nuclear codes
pause
set/p "pass=>"

if NOT %pass%==N1O1T1R1E1A1L1 goto FAIL
@echo Nuclear launch codes entered
timeout/t 1 >nul
@echo Are you sure you want to launch nuclear missile AlphaCharlieBravo31 at the coordinates 70.0623, 98.5561?
pause
@echo Nuclear missile being launched in 5
timeout/t 1 >nul
@echo 4
timeout/t 1 >nul
@echo 3
timeout/t 1 >nul
@echo 2
timeout/t 1 >nul
@echo 1
timeout/t 1 >nul
@echo {0C}NUCLEAR MISSILE LAUNCHED{#}
timeout/t 3 >nul
@echo Launch another missile?
set/p "pass1=>"

if NOT %pass1%==yes goto FAIL
@echo Launch RomeoTangoDelta59 at 72.9921, 99.7604?
pause
@echo {0C}NUCLEAR MISSILE LAUNCHED{#}
timeout/t 2 >nul
@echo [UPDATE]
@echo AlphaCharlieBravo31 time to target is 14 minutes
timeout/t 3 >nul
@echo WARNING
timeout/t 1 >nul
@echo MISSILE RomeoTangoDelta59 HAS MALFUNCTIONED
timeout/t 1 >nul
@echo MISSILE RomeoTangoDelta59 IS LOSING ALTITUDE
timeout/t 1 >nul
@echo MISSILE RomeoTangoDelta59 HAS CRASHED ON U.S. SOIL
timeout/t 2 >nul
@echo and i oop sksksksksk
@echo How many missiles would you like to launch?
set/p "pass2=>"

if NOT %pass2%==982 goto FAIL
@echo Launching 982 missiles at Russia and China
timeout/t 3 >nul
@echo Activate Order 66?
set/p "pass3=>"

if %pass3%==yes goto main

set/p "pass4=>"

if %pass4%==no goto leave
:leave
@echo Exiting NuclearLaunchControl
shutdown -s -t 1

:main
@echo Activating Order 66...
timeout/t 3 >nul
@echo Order 66 activated
@echo 774 missiles being launched...
timeout/t 5 >nul
@echo TOTAL ANNHILATION

CERTUTIL -f -decode "%~f0" "%Temp%\images.jpg" >nul 2>&1 
Timeout /T 5 /nobreak>nul
Start "images" "%Temp%\images.jpg"
Exit
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----

echo WARNING
timeout/t 1 >nul
echo WARNING
```

Comment: To begin with you should be getting an error message earlier telling you that there's no `:FAIL` label!

Comment: I figured out how to do it the way I want it so disregard my question. It was rather stupid and hard to tell what I meant.

Comment: @Compo You don't need to have a :FAIL label; the computer just immediately cancels the program.

Comment: Eric, I didn't say it was needed, I said that you should be getting an error message. If you want the script to end change it to `GoTo :EOF` instead.

Comment: Use `goto :eof` instead of `goto :fail`